# Data not being handled to php form processor through JQuery Ajax (JSON)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm building a form for user registration for my website. I had all the php registration process correct without the use of Json through Jquery AJAX. When I specified it as a datatype (so I can get the response more 'educated') the php file doesn't even read the data sent and the return is [object Object] in the .error response. I've searched the internet and SO in order to try and find a solution but none helped. I think it might be a mistake I made but cant find it. Hope you can help me,
Thanks in advance.

(Please dont mind the english mistakes - I had to write fast. Dont mind the foreigner language comments or titles also.)

Form: (HTML)

```
<form action="">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id='username'>
            <label class='error' for="username" id="userEx">O nome de usuário já existe.</label>
            <label class='error' for="username" id="userDuv">Preencha esse campo, você o utilizará para fazer o Login no sistema.</label><br/>

        <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="senha">
            <label class='error' for="password" id="passDuv">Preencha esse campo.</label><br/>

        <label for="repassword">Repeat Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="repassword" id="reSenha">
            <label class='error' for="repassword" id="repassDuv">Preencha esse campo, ele é necessário para não registrar sua senha de forma errada.</label>
            <label class='error' for="repassword" id="passErr">As duas senhas devem ser iguais.</label><br/>

        <label for="nome">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" id='nome'>
            <label class='error' for="nome" id="nomeDuv">Preencha esse campo, ele será útil na sua identificação no site.</label><br/>


        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id='email'>
            <label class='error' for="email" id="emailDuv">Preencha esse campo com um e-mail válido, ele será utilizado para recuperar sua senha caso necessário.</label><br/>


        <label for="codreg">Code:</label>
            <input type="text" name="codreg" id='codReg'>
            <label class='error' for="codreg" id="codeDuv">Preencha esse campo, para verificar a autenticidade de sua visita.</label>
            <label class='error' for="codreg" id="codeInv">Código Inválido.</label><br/>


            <input type='button' value='Enviar' name='enviar' id='regSub'>
            <input type='reset' name='limpar' value='Limpar' onclick="limpar()">
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="registroProcesso">
        <p>Success!</p>
        <img class="processoImg" src="" alt="Ok!">
    </div>
```

JS Script:

```
 //Form Handler
    $('#regSub').click(function() {
        var username = $('input#username').val();
        if (username == '') {
            $('label#userDuv').show();
            $('input#username').focus();
            return false;
        }

        var pass = $('input#senha').val();
        if (pass == '') {
            $('label#passDuv').show();
            $('input#senha').focus();
            return false;
        }

        var repass = $('input#reSenha').val();
        if (repass == '') {
            $('label#repassDuv').show();
            $('input#reSenha').focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (pass != repass) {
            $('label#passErr').show();
            $('input#senha').focus();
            return false;
        }
        ;

        var nome = $('input#nome').val();
        if (nome == '') {
            $('label#nomeDuv').show();
            $('input#nome').focus();
            return false;
        }

        var email = $('input#email').val();
        if (email == '') {
            $('label#emailDuv').show();
            $('input#email').focus();
            return false;
        }

        var codReg = $('input#codReg').val();
        if (codReg == '') {
            $('label#codeDuv').show();
            $('input#codReg').focus();
            return false;
        }
        ;
        //var dataString = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + pass + '&nome=' + nome + '&email=' + email + '&codreg=' + codReg;
        //alert(dataString); return false;

        var formData = {
            'username': username,
            'password': pass,
            'nome': nome,
            'email': email,
            'codreg': codReg

        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checkregistration.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formData,
            encode: true
        }).done(function(data) {

            if (!data.sucess) {
                if (data.errors.username) {
                    $('label#userEx').show();
                    $('input#username').focus();
                };
                if (data.errors.codigo) {
                    $('label#codInv').show();
                    $('input#codReg').focus();
                };
            } else {
                $('.registroProcesso').show();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.location.href = '../principal.html';
                }, 10000);
            };
        }).error(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
```

PHP Script

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <title>Reghandler</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        ob_start();
        // Valor nulo para as variaveis antes de iniciar
        $username = $password = $nome = $email = $codreg = "";
        $host = "localhost"; // Nome do Host
        $dbuser = "root"; // Mysql username 
        $dbpass = ""; // Mysql password 
        $db_name = "usuarios"; // Database name 
        $tbl_name = "usuarios"; // Table name
        $code_tbl = 'codigos';
        $returnData = array();
        $errors = array();
        $recieved = null;

        mysql_connect("$host", "$dbuser", "$dbpass")or die("cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            $recieved = json_decode($_POST, true);
        }

        if ($recieved != null) {
            $username = test_input($recieved["username"]);
            $password = test_input($recieved["password"]);
            $nome = test_input($recieved["nome"]);
            $email = test_input($recieved["email"]);
            $codreg = test_input($recieved["codreg"]);
        }

        function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
            return $data;
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
            $errors['username'] = 'Nome de usuário já existente.';
        }

        $sqlcode = "SELECT * FROM $code_tbl WHERE codigo='$codreg'";
        $resultcode = mysql_query($sqlcode);
        if (mysql_num_rows($resultcode) == 0) {
            $errors['codigo'] = 'Código de registro não encontrado.';
        }
        if (!empty($errors)) {
            $returnData['success'] = false;
            $returnData['errors'] = $errors;
        } else {
            $returnData['success'] = true;
            $insert = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (username, senha, nome, email)
            VALUES ('$username', '$password','$nome','$email')";
        }
        echo json_encode($returnData);

        ob_end_clean();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was one simple one dumb typo.
I forgot to do the query realy:

```
if (!empty($errors)) {
            $returnData['success'] = false;
            $returnData['errors'] = $errors;
        } else {
            $returnData['success'] = true;
            $insert = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (username, senha, nome, email)
            VALUES ('$username', '$password','$nome','$email')";
```

As I inserted **mysql_query($insert)** after $insert it started working softly. The only problem I still have is how to handle the data sent back from the php.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing datatype from json to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sending a lot of stuff back and not valid json. You need to remove all the html and make sure that you only send json back and nothing else. So no html, no warnings, no echoes, etc. and only one `json_encode()` at the end.

As jQuery encounters a lot of text which it cannot transform to an object and you have specified that the data is valid json, it automatically goes to the error handler.

Comment: The problem is that the script is not even processing. I think it has to do with the arrival, otherwise I would be able to register a user, even if I dont get a message back.

Answer (score 0):

The following portion you can edit like this:

```
var formData = {
            'username': username,
            'password': pass,
            'nome': nome,
            'email': email,
            'codreg': codReg

        };


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checkregistration.php?callback=',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data:JSON.stringify([formData])},
            encode: true
        }).done....etc
```

And in the php page you can return some values like

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . $jsonData
```

where  $jsonData is a variable of type JSON.

And try.

The following blog will help you:

[HTML-PHP Webservice](http://sanjaykumarns.blogspot.in/p/html-php-webservice-jquery-ajax.html)

Comment: I tried to make the changes you suggested but none actually worked... I'm having problems in receiving the info at my php file. If I dont use JSON, it works fine.

Comment: Can you try changing dataType json to jsonp.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the dataType, but with the way that I'm handling it to the php script... I'll see what I get and leave a return. Thanks for your assistance.